# python calling another python script giving error

Tags: python

i have two python scripts like these

parent.py

```
import datetime as dt
from child import showdt
showdt()
```

child.py

```
def showdt():
    print(dt.datetime.now())
```

but when call parent.py i m getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parent.py", line 3, in <module>
    showdt()
  File "F:\works\child.py", line 2, in showdt
    print(dt.datetime.now())
NameError: name 'dt' is not defined
```

what am i missing here

Comment: Have you imported `dt` in `child.py`?

Answer (score 1):

You should import `datetime` in `child.py`. You can remove it from `parent.py`

parent.py

```
from child import showdt
showdt()
```

child.py

```
import datetime as dt
def showdt():
    print(dt.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Is there a way that i import the required modules only once in parent script and the child scripts can reuse them without importing again in child script ?